# Complex mySQL request, division operator

Tags: mysql

I have a database with 3 tables:

```
Bank(Name, City)
Account(Number, Bank)
User(Id, Number)
```

I have to realize the following request.
Select all IDs of the users that have bank accounts at ALL the banks in the city "Hamburg".

I have no idea to approach that, can someone help me?

Comment: "I have no idea". Have you considered looking at any "introduction to mySQL" tutorials? This is a very basic thing to try and do. Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: You may find the answer in looking up what JOINs do in SQL. A quick google search found this promising page http://www.sql-join.com/. Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

I would approach this using aggregation and `having`:

```
select u.id
from account a join
     user u
     on u.number = a.number join
     bank b
     on a.bank = b.name
where b.city = 'Hamburg'
group by u.id
having count(distinct b.name) = (select count(distinct b2.name) from bank b2 where b2.city = 'Hamburg');
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But this throws error #1604 near "from bank b2 where b2.city = 'Hamburg' "